# Python - Remove between indexes of two values if it occurs twice in a list

Tags: python, indexing

Title is definitely confusing, so here's an example: Say I have a list of values `[1,2,3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8]`. I want to remove between the two `1`s in the list, and by pythonic ways it will also end up removing the first `1` and output `[1,4,5,6,7,8]`. Unfortunately, due to my lack of pythonic ability, I have only been able to produce something that removes the first set:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,1,4,5,6,7]
uniques = []
junks = []
for value in a:
    junks.append(value)
    if value not in uniques:
        uniques.append(value)
for value in uniques:
    junks.remove(value)
for value in junks:
    a.remove(value)
    a.remove(value)
a[0] = 1
print(a)
[1,4,5,6,7]
```

Works with the first double occurrence and will not work with the next occurrence in a larger list. I have an idea which is to remove between the index of the first occurrence and the second occurrence which will preserve the second and not have me do some dumb thing like `a[0] = 1` but I'm really not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this do what you asked:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

def f(l):
    x = l.copy()
    for i in l:
        if x.count(i) > 1:
            first_index = x.index(i)
            second_index = x.index(i, first_index + 1)
            x = x[:first_index] + x[second_index:]
    return x
```

So the output of `f(a)` would be `[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and the output of  `f([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 15, 16])` would be `[1, 4, 5, 15, 16]`.

Comment: Nah, the desired output is `[1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` in this case. It wouldn't work either if we had a larger list like `a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 15, 16]`, in which case I'd want to remove between the `5`s as well.

Comment: @Sundrah So you want to remove between ALL duplicate values? And you don't wanna keep both `1`s, only the first one, right?

Comment: what is the desired output with [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]?

Comment: @Markus Meskanen yes, that is the case.

Comment: @Julien Spronck that sort of list will never happen in the algorithm I'm making.

Comment: @Sundrah Could you give us a little more information about what you're trying to do with this "algorithm"?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen it's for a basic maze solver that uses the right hand rule. This is why something like `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` can never happen.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen `a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13]` in your update produced `[1, 4, 5, 6, 5, 10]` instead of `[1, 4, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13]`. Sorry if this is taking too much time, I appreciate you doing this.

Comment: @Sundrah Yeah I had a small typo there, my bad :) But glad to see it finally works :P

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find unique elements you can use set and list

```
mylist = list(set(mylist))
```

Comment: Doing so would not preserve any edge value, so for `[1,2,3,2,1,4,5,6,7]` it would return `[4,5,6,7]` instead of `[1,4,5,6,7]`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 15, 16]
dup = [x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1] # list of duplicates
while dup:
    pos1 = a.index(dup[0])
    pos2 = a.index(dup[0], pos1+1)
    a = a[:pos1]+a[pos2:]
    dup = [x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1]
print a #[1, 4, 5, 15, 16]
```

A more efficient solution would be

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 15, 16]
pos1 = 0
while pos1 < len(a):
    if a[pos1] in a[pos1+1:]:
        pos2 = a.index(a[pos1], pos1+1)
        a = a[:pos1]+a[pos2:]
    pos1 += 1
print a #[1, 4, 5, 15, 16]
```

Comment: @Sundrah is this what you're after?

Comment: yes, it is. They really need to make a thing where you can mark more than one answer correct. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You should really go with a for loop here: `for pos1 in len(a):` sinc eyou're anyways just calling `pos1 += 1` in the while loop.

Comment: The reason I don't use a for loop is because I wanted to change `a` without creating a copy of it

Answer (score 0):

*(This probably isn't the most efficient way, but hopefully it helps)*

Couldn't you just check if something appears twice, if it does you have firstIndex, secondIndex, then:

```python
a=[1,2,3,4,5,1,7,8,9]
b=[]

#do a method to get the first and second index of the repeated number then

for index in range(0, len(a)):
    print index
    if index>firstIndex and index<secondIndex: 
        print "We removed: "+ str(a[index])

    else:
        b.append(a[index])         

print b
```

The output is `[1,1,7,8,9]` which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To do the job you need:

- the first and the last position of duplicated values
- all indexes between, to remove them

Funny thing is, you can simply tell python to do this:

```
# we can use a 'smart' dictionary, that can construct default value:
from collections import defaultdict

# and 'chain' to flatten lists (ranges)
from itertools import chain

a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7]

# build dictionary where each number is key, and value is list of positions:
index = defaultdict(list)
for i, item in enumerate(a):
    index[item].append(i)

# let's take first only and last index for non-single values
edges = ((pos[0], pos[-1]) for pos in index.values() if len(pos) > 1)

# we can use range() to get us all index positions in-between
# ...use chain.from_iterable to flatten our list
# ...and make set of it for faster lookup:
to_remove = set(chain.from_iterable(range(start, end) 
                for start, end in edges))
result = [item for i, item in enumerate(a) if i not in to_remove]
# expected: [1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print result
```

Of course you can make it shorter:

```
index = defaultdict(list)
for i, item in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7]):
    index[item].append(i)
to_remove = set(chain.from_iterable(range(pos[0], pos[-1]) 
                    for pos in index.values() if len(pos) > 1))
print [item for i, item in enumerate(a) if i not in to_remove]
```

This solution has linear complexity and should be pretty fast. The cost is 
additional memory for dictionary and set, so you should be careful for huge data sets. But if you have a lot of data, other solutions that use `lst.index` will choke anyway, because they are O(n^2) with a lot of dereferencing and function calls.